# SVN Framework in C#

Tags: c#, svn

I'm currently working on a small-terminal based game like the good old MUD's, written in C#.
Since I'm hosting it on Googlecode, I used an external .sh-Script to do `svn up` if the project exists and `svn checkout` if it doesn't.
My goal is to include SVN directly into my executable to make it *completely* platform inependent (see mono).
I already googled generic things like "C# SVN" and it always redicted  me to "SharpSVN". Too bad there is no source inside, just some .dll's.

Now what I wanted to do (and ask if it's possible anyways):

- Start the application
- Check if a newer revision is avaible
- Do `svn up`
- Compile
- Launch the new executable if revision numbers aren't equal to what they were last time (aka. newer rev was built)

I'm highly in doubt if it's possible to launch the application after quitting, but *you* surely know more than me;)

EDIT://
Here is the .sh-script which I was running before/am running currently:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
if [ ! -d "$HOME/csdungeon" ]; then
    echo "Which version would you like to download? (G)erman / (E)nglish"
    read getinput
    case "$getinput" in
    G|g) svn checkout http://c-sharp-dungeon.googlecode.com/svn/branches/translations/german/ $HOME/csdungeon
    ;;
    E|e) svn checkout http://c-sharp-dungeon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk $HOME/csdungeon
    ;;
    *) echo "No correct localisazion selected."
    echo "Downloading english version now:"
    svn checkout http://c-sharp-dungeon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk $HOME/csdungeon
    ;;
    esac
else
    cd $HOME/csdungeon
    svn up
    rm $HOME/csdungeon/c-sharp-dungeon.exe
fi
gmcs -out:$HOME/csdungeon/c-sharp-dungeon.exe $HOME/csdungeon/*.cs
mono $HOME/csdungeon/c-sharp-dungeon.exe
fi

if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
    if [ ! -d "$HOME/csdungeon" ]; then
        echo "Which version would you like to download? (G)erman / (E)nglish"
        read getinput
        case "$getinput" in
        G|g) svn checkout https://c-sharp-dungeon.googlecode.com/svn/branches/translations/german/ $HOME/csdungeon --username $1
        ;;
        E|e) svn checkout https://c-sharp-dungeon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk $HOME/csdungeon --username $1
        ;;
        *) echo "No correct localisazion selected."
        echo "Downloading english version now:"
        svn checkout https://c-sharp-dungeon.googlecode.com/svn/trunk $HOME/csdungeon --username $1
        ;;
        esac
    else
        cd $HOME/csdungeon
        svn up
        rm $HOME/csdungeon/c-sharp-dungeon.exe
    fi
    gmcs -out:$HOME/csdungeon/c-sharp-dungeon.exe $HOME/csdungeon/*.cs
    mono $HOME/csdungeon/c-sharp-dungeon.exe
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step-by-step won't work without a helper app. I'd suggest performing the check, then spawning the helper app, closing this one. The helper app then does the download/compile/relauch. I reckon UAC would have a field-day with it. Make sure you consider this from the outset.

Comment: currently, this is done by an external script
I'll add it to my question

Answer (score 3):

SharpSVN is completely open source, here [repository](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/source/browse/sharpsvn/) or you look for some examples?

But AFAIK SharpSVN is not cross-platform library (maybe situation was changed already). So you can browse SharpSVN's source code and check whether it suitable for your needs or try to rely on [Subversion API](http://www.open.collab.net/community/subversion/) directly by yourself.

Comment: Then I just failed to find it. Sorry
I'll see if it does what it's intended to do

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of job for which [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=VS.90).aspx) was invented. I've no idea if it works on mono though.

Comment: Shamefully, it doesn't
My application should be all open for every kind of operating system, even for Nintendo Wii (yes, I'm about to port mono 2.8 for Wii)

Comment: @David Stockinger - and is svn ported to Nintendo Wii? Maybe its simpler to use wget instead, not svn?

Comment: Indeed, it's not
wget is already running, but mono is still somewhat blocky
I'll keep trying